# NPE since updating Activity to use ActionBarActivity and supportlibrary

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an app that usually uses an Activity. I am trying to update it to use ActionBarActivity. I've successfully included the support-v7-appcompat as a project.

I've update the manifest to include in the Activity entry.

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

The activity uses oncreateOptionsMenu, so i've updated the menu file to include my own namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:com.carefreegroup.rr3="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:title="Login "
        android:icon="@android:drawable/presence_online"
        com.carefreegroup.rr3:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/changeuser"
        android:title="Change User"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_delete"
        com.carefreegroup.rr3:showAsAction="never"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/admin"
        android:title="Admin"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_manage"
        com.carefreegroup.rr3:showAsAction="never"/>



</menu>
```

I've made EntryActivity extend ActionBaractivity and it seems to work on Android 4.x but not on Android 5.x

one thing i have noticed in the Console is the following line.

```
android-support-v7-appcompat] Could not find android-support-v7-appcompat.apk!
```

I'm not sure if this is the problem, but it doesn't explain why it runs on one device and not the other?

Can anyone please help me?

```
    03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153): Process: com.carefreegroup.rr3, PID: 31153
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at com.carefreegroup.rr3.EntryActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(EntryActivity.java:1225)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2845)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:275)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivity.java:276)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate$1.onCreatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:79)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.preparePanel(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:979)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.doInvalidatePanelMenu(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:1182)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.access$100(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:79)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateBase$1.run(ActionBarActivityDelegateBase.java:118)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
03-06 12:44:44.427: E/AndroidRuntime(31153):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

manifest:

```
.....
.....

<activity
            android:name=".EntryActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.carefreegroup.rr3.INVALID_CARER_TAG_SCANNED" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />


            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

.

```
public class EntryActivity extends ActionBarActivity{

@Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

.....


}


@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.menuentryoptionsmenu, menu);

        if(isAllowChangeUser.equalsIgnoreCase("false")){
            MenuItem mi = menu.findItem(R.id.changeuser);
            mi.setVisible(false);
        }
        return true;

    }


}
```

.

[EDIT]
I've made a change to make EntryActivity extend ActionBarActivity directly.

The ActionBar now displays on Android 4.x device but not on Android 5.x device.

Has anyone any ideas why?

Comment: where is `super.onCreate(...)` in `NfcBaseActivity` ? and where is (more important!) `setContentView(...)` ... also point the `EntryActivity.java:1231`

Comment: @Selvin Hi sorry i missed those out but they are in there. I've edited the post. i think it is to to with entryActivity having the oncreateOptionsMenu and its super class is the class that extends ActionBarActivity. is there a work around? must i override oncreateoptionsMenu in the superclass?

Comment: setContentView is important when you using ActionBarActivity ... It creates "fake actionbar" (takes your view/layout and put it in own which has "fake/emulated actionbar") ... without this call getActionBar will return null and it is not possible to setup menu ...

Comment: @Selvin ah ok, Well i have created a superclass called NfcBaseActivity that a lot of Activities extend. It has some common functionality but has no setContentView. it does however extend ActionbarActivity. How can i have anActivity extend my superclass in this way and still have ActionBarActivity functionality?

Comment: @Selvin would it be the case of putting the common functionality into each subclass(replicating code) and the make every subclass extend ActionBarActivity?

Comment: @Selvin I have made the above Activity directly extend ActionBarActivity and it works fine on Android 4.x. It has the above error when creating the optionMenu on Android 5.x do you have any ideas why?

Comment: Where and how do you set `isAllowChangeUser`? That's what's `null`.

Comment: @CommonsWare Hi Mark, I understand that the NPE was on this line but what i don't understand is why there is a difference between Android 4 and Android 5. The isAllowChangeUser is a boolean that gats set when you first install the app. Normally, before i extended the ActionBarActivity class, the user would be prompted to enter a companyID(Integer). i would then call a webservice that would populate this variable. The app crashes on my Android 5 phone as soon as you install the app, the user doesn't get chance to download the company settings and populate this variable.

Comment: @CommonsWare it works when i extend Activity but when i extend ActionbarActivity it crashes. this makes me think that ActionbarActivity must try to create the optionsmenu before displaying the Activity  and giving the user chance to download the congig setings and populate this variable or something along those lines?

Comment: "why there is a difference between Android 4 and Android 5" -- well, since I don't know where that string comes from, I cannot really answer that. "this makes me think that ActionbarActivity must try to create the optionsmenu before displaying the Activity or something along those lines?" -- you definitely should not be relying upon the timing of `onCreateOptionsMenu()` with respect to when, say, `super.onCreate()` returns.

Comment: @CommonsWare When the user installs the app, EntryActivity is the launcher Activity.This Activity prompts the user to enter the companyid to download the config settings that populates isallowChangeUser. It  seems that when i extend Activity, Android launches this Activity and displays the dialogbox that prompts the user to enter the companyID, then executes onCreateOptionsMenu. it seems like the opposite with ActionBarActivity, atleast with android 5. How can i make onCreateOptionsMenu execute successfully when it relies on a runtime variable that is set after the Activity is instantiated?

Comment: You move your logic out of `onCreateOptionsMenu()` into a separate method, other than finding the `MenuItem`. When *both* conditions are met (you have your value, and the `MenuItem` is available), then you invoke that separate method. If `onCreateOptionsMenu()` sees that `isAllowChangeUser` is `null`, it just stashes the `MenuItem` in a data member that the separate method can then use.

Comment: @CommonsWare If you'd like to make that an answer, i'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, it is not safe to assume the order of execution of `onCreate()` and `onCreateOptionsMenu()`. That really depends on the action bar implementation. I can see `onCreateOptionsMenu()` being invoked during `super.onCreate()` processing, after `onCreate()` ends, or even conceivably before `onCreate()` begins (though that last one seems unlikely).

If you have logic that is dependent on both `onCreate()` and `onCreateOptionsMenu()` doing some work, the recipe that I use is:

- Move that work into a dedicated private method
- Have that method confirm that the the time is ripe to do the work (e.g., the `MenuItem` was retrieved from `onCreateOptionsMenu()` and the whatever-it-was was set up in `onCreate()`)
- Invoke that method from both `onCreate()` and `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, after each of those methods has done its piece of the work